# Made + Advance and Made + Afford?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm flummoxed by how [these bolded clauses from The Theory of Moral Sentiments by Adam Smith](http://www.econlib.org/library/Topics/Details/invisiblehand.html) should be parsed, structured, and interpreted. I'm not asking about its philosophy.

> The produce of the soil maintains at all times nearly that number of inhabitants which it is capable of maintaining. The rich only select from the heap what is most precious and agreeable. They consume little more than the poor, and in spite of their natural selfishness and rapacity, though they mean only their own conveniency, though the sole end which they propose from the labours of all the thousands whom they employ, be the gratification of their own vain and insatiable desires, they divide with the poor the produce of all their improvements. They are led by an invisible hand to make nearly the same distribution of the necessaries of life, **which would have been *made***, had the earth been divided into equal portions among all its inhabitants, and thus without intending it, without knowing it, ***advance* the interest of the society, and *afford* means to the multiplication of the species.**

Is ***made*** supposed to be coupled with ***advance*** & ***afford*** to form a verb clause, so:
"which would have been made .... advance .... and afford ..." ?

If so, could someone please explicate this? These sound aberrant but novel to me (I'm cognisant that this book was published in 1759):
● "which would have been made advance the interest of the society"
● "which would have been made afford means to the multiplication of the species.

Wouldn't it be more natural to write
● "which would have advanced the interest ..., and afforded means ..." ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Mark Thorin. The sentence could be split into two and the punctuation modernised, which might help your difficulties:

> They are led by an invisible hand to make nearly the same distribution
>   of the necessaries of life which would have been made had the earth
>   been divided into equal portions among all its inhabitants. Thus, and
>   without intending it, without knowing it, [they] advance the interest of the
>   society, and afford means to the multiplication of the species.

Answer (score 0):

"would have been made" is relative to the conditional "had the earth been divided"

That is : "if the earth had been divided ... , then the same distribution ... would have been made".

After the "and thus", it is the conclusion that there is an invisible hand.

The text between "which would" and ""inhabitants" is an interpolated clause.

Comment: Thank you. +1 ; SE doesn't admit of multiple acceptances.